# GCloud Storage Rewrite operation performance/latency

Tags: google-cloud-storage

What is the average time that a rewrite API operation takes to complete rewrite for different sizes of objects?

Assume: rewrite of the same object, same source and destination but with different CMEK (of KMS).

There is no documentation regarding this. I need this information to estimate how much time a batch re-write job takes to complete when there are many objects.

I understand that latency might be a hard question to answer, but I'm only interested in whether it finishes in seconds or minutes etc(for example for an object that is couple of GBs say 3GB).

Since all of rewrite happens inside google components itself, I'm unable to figure this out. Any help or documentation related to this would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

If the source and destination buckets are in the same location and storage class, rewrite will be a fast (metadata-only) operation.
Otherwise the bytes have to be copied by the service, so time grows with object size and also will be slower if the source and destination are far apart (e.g., across an ocean). You can try doing some benchmarking experiments if you want a more precise answer than that.

Comment: my usecase rewrites the object CMEK header for changing encryption key